# Allowed to board without Schengen visa, can I get reimbursed for costs incurred?

Tags: visas, schengen

I was allowed to board a flight to Poland. I was supposed to transit to the US through Germany after that. But, I had no Schengen, so the Polish kept me there. I had to lose my ticket and pay for a no stop ticket to the US after that, plus stay over 24 hours in the airport in Poland. Would some one know if I could get reimbursed for my extra travel costs from any entity?

Comment: But if you hadn't been allowed to board in the first place, you would also have lost your ticket and have had to buy a new one. So not sure how big a difference it made in the end.

Comment: Did you book all the tickets as one trip? Did you book yourself or through an agent? It's possible you can get a refund for the unused part of the original, but I doubt there's much of a way to get the extra costs back. As always check all applicable travel insurance (i.e. on your credit card if you paid using on) just in case.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a couple recent questions. You're likely out of luck, Sam!  it's interesting you had to stay over in the airport, I guess in a visa free zone or something?

Comment: Thanks, all.
I did buy it myself online forgetting the visa rules. It had been while since I passed through more than one European country. I was roaming around the Polish airport. Cost double the ticket price. It would have been cheaper to buy the ticket from the home country.

Answer (score 3):

Formally, it would depend on the airline's conditions of carriage and any relevant consumer protection laws in the country where you bought the ticket. But in all likelihood you won't be able to get anything, conditions of carriage usually explicitly specify that passengers are expected to make sure that they meet all relevant visa requirements.

The Polish state certainly will not compensate you or anybody. In fact, they could (and probably will) fine the airline for letting you board the plane in the first place.